# APDU Commands in Delphi

Tags: delphi, command, apdu

I've spent a day reading about APDU commands, never used them before and I'm still not sure how do I code a procedure/function in Delphi to communicate with a Smart Card, any help/advice would be much appreciated.
The Smart Card has two applets installed. This command selects the Secure element
applet and routes subsequent APDU commands to it.

IsoCase: Case4Short

Class: 0x00

Instruction: 0xa4

Data: 0x10 0xA0 0x00 0x00 0x07 0x48 0x46 0x4A 0x49 0x2D 0x54 0x61 0x78 0x43 0x6F 0x72 0x65

Le: 0x00

Example: 0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0x10 0xA0 0x00 0x00 0x07 0x48 0x46 0x4A 0x49 0x2D 0x54 0x61 0x78 0x43 0x6F
0x72 0x65 0x00

How is the procedure supposed to look like, do I need to use any components, libraries, dlls? No idea what needs to be between begin and end tags. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sending a command APDU can be done thru [SCardTransmit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardtransmit). And like most other things (reading a file, printing a document...) it requires a few steps before until you can do that (i.e. selecting the card reader you want to communicate with, checking if a card is inserted...).

Comment: Thank you for your answer kind sir, I'll give it a good read.